# Undesirable Double Quotes When Exporting a Tab Delimited File

Tags: sql, oracle, toad, csv

When I export my SQL results into a tab delimited file, double quotes surround a  handful of my records. I don't know why this is. I am assuming it is because some of the record names have a special character breaking something?

A simple solution would be to go in and do a find and replace on double quotes, but that seems a bit improper.

Comment: What RDBMS?  How are you exporting?

Comment: Oracle RDMBS. Copying the results from SQL, then exporting to a tab delimited from excel. (Using TOAD as my SQL editor)

Comment: I would suspect those columns have some records that contain tabs.

Comment: The columns do not contain tabs...

Comment: Could it be that the data contains commas, another popular delimiter, and it's inadvertently adding the quotation marks as qualifiers?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this with fields that contained commas, even when loading a tab delimited file.  A field qualifier and "Always Qualify Fields" prevented the fields with commas being quoted in the DB.